# GCD and for loops

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, grand-central-dispatch, glkit

I was wondering what is the difference between using a for loop, and using the `dispatch_apply` function of GCD and couldn't find an answer in the documentation nor in questions here.

Also, will using the GCD function in a runtime situation as a GLKit render/update method will produce better results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, will using the GCD function in a runtime situation as a GLKit render/update method will produce better results?

The only way to answer that question is to try it and measure the performance.

Comment: Well ,just to make it clear - I ran some tests and the GCD is more heavy then the for loop, I suppose that it has a high overhead.

Comment: @Mr.Awesome Have you thought about batching up the iterations?  i.e. if you have 1,000 iterations to do and four CPUs you could `dispatch_apply` four tasks each going through 250 cases in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states :

> The dispatch_apply() function provides data-level concurrency through a "for (;;)" loop like primitive:

This means that the code block called by dispatch_apply will not be called sequentially like the for but can execute concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, I added another question, if you can help.