# Parallelize this algorithm to make it faster

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch, matrix-inverse

As a challenge, I was asked to make a parallel algorithm for inverting a matrix. I mainly looked at [this paper](http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ernet.in/~baidurya/publications/girish%20et%20al%202013.pdf) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230067/large-matrix-inversion) while doing research for it.

Before I tried to write my own code, I stumbled across [someone else's implementation](http://hullooo.blogspot.com/2011/02/matrix-inversion-by-gauss-jordan.html).

I come from an objective-c background, so I immediately thought of using GCD for this task. I also came across something called [POSIX](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) which seems more low-level, and might be apt for this task if GCD won't work--I don't know.

My naive attempt for parallelizing this was just to replace every for-loop with a `dispatch_apply`, which worked (the product of the original and the inverse produces the identity matrix). However, that just slowed things down significantly (about 20x as slow at a glance). I see that there are [SO questions on GCD and for-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330275/gcd-and-for-loops), but I'm mainly interested in what a better approach could be to this, not links to those answers which I've already read. Is it possible that the problem is the way I'm creating the dispatch queue, or maybe the fact that I'm only using one dispatch queue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PARALLEL true

void invertMatrixNonParallel(double **matrix, long n);
void invertMatrixParallel(double **matrix, long n, dispatch_queue_t q);

void invertMatrixParallel(double **matrix, long n, dispatch_queue_t q)
{
    __block double r;
    __block long temp;

    dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t i) {
        dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t j) {
            matrix[i][j + n] = (j == i) ? 1 : 0;
        });
    });
    /* using gauss-jordan elimination */

    dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t j) {
        temp=j;

        /* finding maximum jth column element in last (n-j) rows */

        dispatch_apply(n - j - 1, q, ^(size_t i) {
            if (matrix[i + j + 1][j] > matrix[temp][j])
            {
                temp = i + j + 1;
            }
        });

        /* swapping row which has maximum jth column element */

        if(temp!=j)
        {
            double *row = matrix[j];
            matrix[j] = matrix[temp];
            matrix[temp] = row;
        }

        /* performing row operations to form required identity matrix out of the input matrix */
        dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t i) {
            r = matrix[i][j];

            if (i == j)
            {
                dispatch_apply(2 * n, q, ^(size_t k) {
                    matrix[i][k]/=r ;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_apply(2 * n, q, ^(size_t k) {
                    matrix[i][k]-=(matrix[j][k]/matrix[j][j])*r ;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

void invertMatrixNonParallel(double **matrix, long n)
{
    double temporary, r;
    long i, j, k, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = n; j < n * 2; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = (j == i + n) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    /* using gauss-jordan elimination */

    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        temp=j;

        /* finding maximum jth column element in last (n-j) rows */

        for(i=j+1; i<n; i++)
            if(matrix[i][j]>matrix[temp][j])
                temp=i;

        /* swapping row which has maximum jth column element */

        if(temp!=j)
        {
            for(k=0; k<2*n; k++)
            {
                temporary=matrix[j][k] ;
                matrix[j][k]=matrix[temp][k] ;
                matrix[temp][k]=temporary ;
            }
        }

        /* performing row operations to form required identity matrix out of the input matrix */

        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                r=matrix[i][j];
                for(k=0; k<2*n; k++)
                    matrix[i][k]-=(matrix[j][k]/matrix[j][j])*r ;
            }
            else
            {
                r=matrix[i][j];
                for(k=0; k<2*n; k++)
                    matrix[i][k]/=r ;
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Main

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long i, j, k;
    const long n = 5;
    const double range = 10.0;
    __block double **matrix;
    __block double **invertedMatrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * n);

    matrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * n);
    invertedMatrix = malloc(sizeof(double *) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
        invertedMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * 2);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = drand48() * range;
            invertedMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    clock_t t;

#if PARALLEL
    dispatch_queue_t q1 = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.queue1", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    t = clock();
    invertMatrixParallel(invertedMatrix, n, q1);
#else
    t = clock();
    invertMatrixNonParallel(invertedMatrix, n);
#endif

    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t * 1000)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

    printf("\n%s took %f milliseconds to execute \n\n", (PARALLEL == true) ? "Parallel" : "Non-Parallel", time_taken);

    printf("Here's the product of the inverted matrix and the original matrix\n");
    double product[n][n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                sum += matrix[i][k] * invertedMatrix[k][j + n];
            }
            product[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

    // should print the identity matrix
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            printf("%5.2f%s", product[i][j], (j < n - 1) ? ", " : "\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output for parallel:

```
Parallel took 0.098000 milliseconds to execute
```

For nonparallel:

```
Non-Parallel took 0.004000 milliseconds to execute
```

For both:

```
Here's the product of the inverted matrix and the original matrix
 1.00, -0.00, -0.00,  0.00, -0.00
 0.00,  1.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00
 0.00, -0.00,  1.00, -0.00,  0.00
-0.00, -0.00, -0.00,  1.00,  0.00
 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  1.00
```

Please, no answers that are just links, I'm only using SO as a last resort.

Comment: Try it for a higher rank matrix. I doubt the parallel solution would be quicker for a 5x5 matrix.

Comment: @Bathsheba Good suggestion. There's currently a problem with higher ranks for the parallel version. I believe that's because of the nested `dispatch_apply`s using the same queue, so I'll try to fix that and get back to this.

Comment: how big matrices you want (fit to memory twice? or load from disc?) also do not forget to take in mind that motherboard cache size is limited if you cross that barrier and have not your computation possible on sub-data only then the parallel version will became much much slower see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21379840/2521214

Comment: you use GEM which use `if` heavily and also need some pre ordering of rows (which is used for which diagonal 1) to avoid invalid results (on wrong order the inverse exists but it is not found especially for matrices containing many zeros) this slows thing down a little have you tried computation of Inverse via Determinant which is more suited for parallel ? (but you have to be careful with recursion stack/heap trashing) or you have to be stuck with GEM ?

Comment: @Spektre, I do not have to use GEM. Please, if you know a better parallel matrix inversion algorithm. I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @doctordoder look for computing inverse matrix by `Cramer's rule` for example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule but there are tons of papers and scripts/books about this in Linear Algebra. btw this is more precise because you have only one division at the end instead of many in GEM

Comment: @doctordoder here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25176378/2521214 is mine inverse matrix in C++ via Cramer`s rule for 4x4 matrices (used for OpenGL transform matrices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) As already mentioned in comments you need bigger matrix. Creating of parallel thread takes some overhead time, so you can't make more quicker parallel version if it takes too small amount of time at all. Even if you will manage to achieve better performance for small matrix it's hard to measure exactly.

1)

```
dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t i) {
    dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t j) {
        matrix[i][j + n] = (j == i) ? 1 : 0;
    });
});
```

There is not much sense in parallelization of every nested loop. There is no sense of adding every single operation one by one in dispatch queue because it still takes some overhead so it's better to add some nontrivial blocks.

```
dispatch_apply(n, q, ^(size_t i) {
    for (j = n; j < n * 2; ++j) {
        matrix[i][j + n] = (j == i) ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Is enough.

2) You need to learn about thread safety and understand your algorithm well or you may run into unpredictable and non reproducible misbehavior of your application. I'm not sure if there are many loops which can be paralleled efficiently and really safely except for mentioned above initialization and one marked with /* performing row operations to form required identity matrix out of the input matrix */

So you probably need to find some specific parallel matrix inversion algorithm.